# does a list of all devices exist where google blacklisted webgl?

Tags: android, webgl

I would like to know on which devices google blacklisted webgl, if such a list exists it would  be nice to get a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The list for Chrome browser appears to be here (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/gpu/config/software_rendering_list_json.cc), thanks to @PaulIrish.

Note that, Google has several different rendering engines, and several browsers. So you need to be specific about the rendering engine and the browser itself.

Comment: That a list of GPU's, do you know if there is a list of devices?